# Navigation Shadow cut not navigation bar

Tags: ios, ios8, navigation, ios9

[image]

How to solve this shadow issue ? I am getting sired navigation shadow while interactive pop .

what can be possibly fix to solve this issue.

Comment: How do you add the shadow?

Comment: I have not make any changes its default navigation bar only. just change is first view controller has navigation bar invisible and in second navigation bar is visible.